# How to create a custom javascript function and call it anywhere in marklogic?

Tags: marklogic

I want to create a javascript function and load it into my own modules database and  I want to call that function.

Initially, I was trying it with xquery function. I loaded the xquery function into my own modules database(like top-songs-mods). When I try to call that function I'm getting the following exception.

XDMP-MODNOTFOUND: (err:XQST0059)

I've also added the execute, update, read permissions to the document.

After that, when I loaded the same xquery function to the MODULES database(which is there by default) i can able to call that function.

I was referring to this document https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/import_modules#id_26329

In my app-server, root is set to '/' and modules is set to 'top-songs-mods'.

Can anyone explain, how to load a module into our own modules database and import it from library module or main module and call that function anywhere?

Comment: Can you show the code that inserts the JavaScript module and the code that requires the JavaScript module?

Does the require code look like http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/jsref/functions#id_21536 ?

Comment: curl --anyauth --user admin:admin -X PUT -T test.sjs "http://localhost:8045/v1/documents?uri=/test.sjs&database=top-songs-mods"

Comment: 'use strict';
const test=require("/test.sjs");
test.myFunction();

Comment: curl defaults the content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded for POST and might do the same for PUT.  Using the -i or -v header should show if that's occuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page explains how to create a simple SJS module:
https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/sjs/javascript-modules

I created a local file called `test.sjs` with the following content:

```
module.exports= {
  myFunction: test
};

function test() {
 return "test";
}
```

Using a similar curl command to what you posted, I PUT the `test.sjs` file into the `example-modules` database:

```
curl --anyauth --user admin:admin -X PUT -T test.sjs "localhost:8123/v1/documents?uri=/test.sjs&database=example-modules"
```

And then executing the following code in Query Console against that app server that has  `example-modules` as the modules database:

```
const test = require("/test.sjs");
test.myFunction();
```

It executes successfully and returns: `test`

Comment: I did the same as you did, still I'm getting this exception. [javascript] XDMP-MODNOTFOUND: const test = require("/test.sjs"); -- Module /test.sjs not found